# Flex hero mobile set backgroundcolor

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder, flex4.5

I'm currently working with Flex Hero mobile 4.5 to develop a mobile program.
I have searched some forums allready but nobody can help me with this.

How do you change the backgroundcolor of your mobile program.
I have allready tried to use:

```
this.setStyle("backgroundColor","0x00FFFF");
```

Does somebody has an idea on how to do this? You should help me a lot.

Kind regards,

Thibault Heylen

Answer (score 1):

In ViewNavigatorApplication

write flowing code

```
 <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        s|View{
            backgroundColor:#000000;
        }
 </fx:Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange, there's only `opaqueBackground` property on the View classes which doesn't seem to do much, so you might have to just fill it with a Rectangle.

Comment: I was thinking this too but thougt there would be a better way to do this.